# Showing that a first countable space is compactly generated

Tags: general-topology

I am following the proof in Lee's "Intro to Topological Manifolds", Lemma 4.94. My question is: do we need to assume that the space is Hausdorff? The proof runs like:

Let $A \subseteq X$ be such that for any compact $K$, $A \cap K$ is closed in $K$. Let $x \in \bar A$. By first countability, $x$ is a limit of some $(x_n)_n \subseteq A$. Then $K:= \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{ x \}$ is compact and so $A \cap K$ is closed in $K$. Now, *if* $X$ is Hausdorff, then $K$ is closed and so $A \cap K$ is closed in $X$, and so, since $x$ is a limit of $(x_n)_n$ (*the* limit, in this case), it follows that $x \in A$. But if $X$ is not necessarily Hausdorff, I don't see how to use the closedness of $A \cap K$ *in* $K$ to come to the conclusion (for example, if $K = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $A = \mathbb{Q}$, then $A \cap K$ is obviously closed in $K$, but the limit of a sequence in $A \cap K$ doesn't necessarily lie in $A \cap K$)

Comment: $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ is not even compact...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in \overline{A}$ we indeed find $x_n, n \in \Bbb N$, all in $A$, so that $x_n \to x$ in $X$, and then it's elementary to see that $K=\{x_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{x\}$ is compact. Indeed, then $A \cap K$ is closed in $K$ and as $x \in \overline{\{x_n\mid n \in N\}}^{(K)} \subseteq A \cap K$ it follows that $x \in A \cap K$ and in particular $x \in A$. I don't see where we use Hausdorffness in either $K$ or $X$.

Comment: My confusion was with the fact that $x \in \overline{ \{ x_n | n \in N \}}^{(K)}$. I didn't see why if $(x_n)_n$ has a limit in $X$, it must have the same limit inside a subspace of $X$; but of course in this case it does, since $x \in K$!